# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Quotation mark in propery name

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I have in my software the following code:

```
MyText = "some\" Text"
$(MyDiv).parent().siblings("[data-value=" + CorrectCharacters(MyText) + "]");

CorrectCharacters = function (text) {
        return text.toString().replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1')
}
```

MyText may contain any text, and usually it works, unless it contains " in the middle.
In that case, I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: data-text="some\" Text]
```

I have tried the suggested solutions for other questions like:

```
MyText = 'some\\" Text'
```

But they did not work for me.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Add a `+` for `("[data-value=" + CorrectCharacters(MyText)` and remove the last `'` on that line

Comment: `.siblings("[data-value="CorrectCharacters(MyText) + "]")';` Should be `.siblings("[data-value=" + CorrectCharacters(MyText) + "]");`. You're missing a `+`, and had a `'` too many.

Comment: I corrected it. Yet, i am facing the same issue

Comment: It's a textual field(string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that eventually worked for me:

```
if (MyText.includes('"')) {
            var simbling = $(MyDiv).parent().siblings();
            for (var i = 0; i < simbling.size() ; i++)
            {
                if (simbling[i].children[1].innerHTML == MiniCorrectCharacters(MyText)) {
                    $tw = simbling[i];
                    oItem = {
                        Text: simbling[i].children[1].innerHTML,
                    };
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if ($tw.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

That should work better :

```
$(MyDiv).parent().siblings("[data-value=" + CorrectCharacters(MyText) + "]");
```

I removed the wild ' and added a + in order to properly concatenate the variable.

Comment: Please don't answer "typo" questions. They're explicitly off-topic.